# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, maven, struts2, jackson, eclipse-mars

I was **able to run the same Struts 2 application** in previous version of Eclipse.

But when I tried to run it in Mars.1, it is giving the below exception:

```
Nov 25, 2015 1:16:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/GoogleChart] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
```

My POM looks like this :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>AutoPlat</groupId>
  <artifactId>AutoPlat</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.5</version>
  <name>AutoPlat</name>
  <description>AutoPlat</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>

  </dependencyManagement>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

And, web.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
    <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>
<!--    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PieChartServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>chart.PieChartServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PieChartServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PieChartServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>DashBoard.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

What is the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Caused by:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is missing in the classpath

---

I guess that [the underline problem](http://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/) is that:

> ### Maven
>
> Now that Codehaus no longer serves up Maven repositories, you will
>   need to change your configuration.
>
> If your configuration is not updated and you slam our redirector, then
>   you may be served invalid JAR files with status 200 to encourage you
>   to update your configuration.
>
> ### Making Maven Work
>
> #### settings.xml
>
> In **~/.m2/settings.xml** you can update the URL to be used for specific
>   repositories.
>
> For example:
>
> ```xml
> <repositories>
>   <repository>
>     <id>codehaus-mule-repo</id>
>     <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
>     <url>
>       https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
>     </url>
>     <layout>default</layout>
>   </repository>
> </repositories>
> ```

Also note that that artifact [has been migrated](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13) and evoluted a lot since **1.9.13**, now it [has reached **2.6.3**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.6.3):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```